# Bisection Method Infinite Floating Point Digits

Tags: python, algorithm, bisection

I'm trying to create a program utilizing the Bisection Method (there are quite a lot of unused variables and confusing comments, so just ignore those). The value being outputted is fine, except it's getting stuck in an infinite loop and printing an infinite number of floating point digits. Isn't the epsilon supposed to stop this from happening? Here's my code:

```
total_cost = 1000000
downpayment = 0.25
amount_needed = total_cost * downpayment
annual_salary = int(input("Enter the starting salary: "))
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
num_of_months = 36

#needs changing
epsilon = .01

num_of_guesses = 0
low = 0
high = 100
ans = (high + low) / 2.0
ans = round(ans, 2)

#might need changing
while (num_of_months * (monthly_salary * (ans / 100)))**2 - amount_needed >= epsilon:
    print("Low:", low, "High:", high, "Answer:", ans)
    num_of_guesses  = num_of_guesses + 1
    if num_of_months * (monthly_salary * (ans / 100)) < amount_needed:
        low = ans
    elif num_of_months * (monthly_salary * (ans / 100)) > amount_needed:
        high = ans
    ans = (high + low) / 2.0
    ans = round(ans, 2)
print("Number Of Guesses: ", num_of_guesses)
```

It's probably something really stupid but I honestly don't know what's going on XD

Comment: Instead of asking us to ignore the unused variables and confusing comments, you could just remove them to make it easier for us to read your code.

Comment: What is `ans**2 - 100` supposed to represent?  You're testing that to determine when to end the loop - but you're doing absolutely nothing to adjust `ans` to minimize that expression.  Instead, you're adjusting `ans` to try to satisfy the equation `num_of_months * (monthly_salary * (ans / 100)) == amount_needed` - so the error in *that* equation is what you should be comparing to `epsilon`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for solutions y = f(x) where y is 0, and you want to bisect intervals on the x-axis and check epsilon on x. Therefore, it might be easier for you to write this function separately, rather than embed it into your bisect code, so you can keep yourself straight on what's what. You shouldn't care what y is, just whether it is greater or less than 0, so epsilon has nothing to do with the computed function result.